# How do I find the Git commit which changed a file to its current state?

Tags: git

For a given file (and commitish), how do I find the commit which changed that file to be what it is at that point?

For instance, if I have MyFile.txt and tag "V1-2-3", how do I find out what was the last commit which updated MyFile.txt to make it whatever it is at that tag?

To be clear, this isn't asking for a diff, I'm just trying to find the commit info (in this case the user and comment) for the last commit on that file.

Comment: Hm, is it as simple as [checking out the tag and] doing `git log -n 1 MyFile.txt`?

Comment: I think Sergio is correct here - that shows me the commit.  Is there any way of doing this without checking out the tag first?

Comment: Aha!
git log -n 1 v1-2-3 -- MyFile.txt does it.

Sergio, if you add that as an answer I'll accept it.